Reducing travel time in short distance space travel
In the civilization I'm working out, the distances between the celestial bodies are rather short (between 200'000 km and and 20'000'000 km) when it comes to space travel.
Economically, this society is organized in a similar way to our real world counterpart, meaning Capitalism is dominant. So state- and privately owned Service Providers/Enterprises will compete and operate these ships and launching/arriving facilities.
However, quickly accelerating a space craft without weakening it's structural integrity is still quite complicated.
Other factors coming into play:

On these worlds, there are very few fossil mineral resources left

Gravity onboard is ensured by rotation

When it comes to technology, this civilization is ahead of humanity. Meaning that they've perfectioned hydrogen engines in most of their vehicles and vessel types. They are using renewable energy or nuclear fusion respectively, wherever it's the best option.

There are no ground based launching facilities, instead the space ships will depart and arrive at space stations.

Inertial damping systems don't exist. So the accelerating and decelerating phases will occupy most of the flight path

Passengers expect a certain level of comfort, service and entertainment during longer trips. It should be at least comparable to a long haul flight with an established real-live airline.

Selling Products to customers waiting for departure or after arrival is a significant economic factor for a variety of Corporations.

These worlds are still fragmented into different states and factions. Terrorism is a real threat. So service providers will have to comply with security standards imposed by governments, which may impact how vessels are constructed and driven.

Passengers are used to gravity on board, so they want to walk/sit instead of floating/swimming in the air. I assume the latter option would be a hazard if the ship is crowded.

I'm also assuming that passengers prioritize arriving at their destination, instead of spending days on a ship.


My Question is: How can I optimize the ship design so that they can minimize travel time, the acceleration process will not rip the ships apart, without damaging cargo and putting passengers into danger? The issue with flying particles/projectiles damaging ships will be thought about in another question

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Why do you need faster acceleration?
I'm not sure you realize it but the distances you are talking about (200,000 km - 200,000,000 km) are, from an astrodynamics perspective, tiny. Like, really tiny. For reference, the Moon is about 384,400 km away on average. If the ISS were built like a regular spaceship to withstand maneuvering accelerations to take it into a higher orbit, travelling that distance would take hours if the engine could do meaningful g-scale acceleration continuously (keep in mind that a ship orbiting an Earth-like planet starts with around 10 km/s velocity) and days at most if they had to do a short maneuver to get to an elliptical transfer orbit (given that it only took a few days for the Apollo missions to reach the Moon, which is farther away than your proposed planets).
The other factor is that if that's how far away a planet is then travel time will be faster because half the time you'll be falling towards the planet rather than falling away from one. In an elliptical orbit, objects speed up on their way towards the gravitating body and they slow down on their way away; for a starship travelling between your binary planets, they can spend much more of their journey accelerating just by the planet's gravity because past the halfway point between the planets their destination will begin pulling on them harder than their origin.
Even for longer spaceflights on the order of 200M km, you can still expect very fast travel times, measured in days at most if the ship can continuously accelerate at 1 g. Some quick math shows you that with a fusion-powered torchship starting at 10 km/s, you can travel 200,000,000 km in just under 3 and a half days, all while getting to a peak velocity of around 0.4% of the speed of light. For an interplanetary journey (albeit a much smaller one), that travel time is extremely fast. It takes us 2024 astronauts that long to travel to the moon, and with your torchship you could travel the same time and get a little under a thousand times the distance. For a shorter journey, some more math indicates that the journey would take under two hours - a quarter of the time than it takes for me to go to my cabin up north.
Here, speed is not your issue. Well, it is your issue, but it's not the issue that you think it is. With a fusion engine, you can pull in interstellar gas as highly-efficient fuel and produce a large amount of thrust, so your acceleration problems are solved. The issue that arises is the fact that, traveling at 0.4% of the speed of light for long-distance journeys, not only will you not be able to maneuver effectively for emergency course corrections to avoid small asteroids that evaded detection, but those asteroids will be hitting you at what you see to be approximately 0.4% of the speed of light. If the exponent in the equation $E_k=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ doesn't terrify you right now, it should. A one-milligram micrometeorite will strike with the force of a little over 719 megajoules of energy; that's equivalent to about 171 kilograms of TNT. If something larger, like a one-ton asteroid, happens to be in your way, you won't be able to get out of the way, and it will hit your ship with the energy of a nuclear bomb.
How you get up to speed is a solved problem. What you need to figure out is how to deal with stuff that gets in your way, because if it takes a day and a half for you to get up to speed (which for long journeys it will), it will take at least a day and a half to slow down without crushing the passengers, and you might not have that long to slow down before you plow into the asteroid at a significant fraction of $c$.
The issue isn't necessarily even that you can't maneuver out of the way - you could easily burn in a direction perpendicular to your current path, and since components of velocities are independent of each other you could easily dodge just about anything. The issue is that you're moving very fast and the things you're trying to avoid are very small. If you had a super-awesome telescope array aboard your ship capable of detecting every dangerous mote of dust within a 1,000 km radius of your ship in the forward direction (which is already science fiction), and it detected a tiny little piece of ice in your path at the outside of that radius, you would have about 834 milliseconds to turn your ship ninety degrees (which, if you don't want to kill the passengers who are distant from the reaction wheels and will experience higher rotation-induced gravity, will take much longer than that) to burn perpendicular and dodge the micrometeorite. It takes longer to shout "micrometeorite" than for a torchship at 0.4% $c$ to cross that distance; the ship's engineer wouldn't even have time to relay the information to the captain before it's too late.
Of course there are fun solutions to this problem - one of which is actually intentionally taking slow journeys - but that's a different question entirely.
Also, these short travel times with 1-g torchships actually make perfect economic sense as well; I gather from your question that that's an important aspect of your worldbuilding. On a long journey, the ship needs only tune down the engine to round off the total length to a nice and even 4 days. Then, the passengers get to have nice, comfy, low-g cruise experiences in space, all while en route to their destination. If we're talking about a huge The Expanse-style ship with onboard living spaces, major source of entertainment (and revenue for the captain and their organization) could be lower-gravity swimming, among other things. For shorter journeys, I would imagine that it would be sort of like a train ride: you take the dinner ship and can get nice food (cooked beforehand and frozen-reheated onboard) while you wait to arrive at your nearby destination. The passengers have a good time and get transportation to their destination (barring micrometeorite impacts), and the organization owning the starship sells tickets.

Thank you for your answer. Yes, the travel experiences could be very diverse, from the 1-g torchships you suggested to more "train-ride" akin trips, which maybe would also resemble your average real world flights (?)
Anyway great points, despite i initially asked the question poorly.

I also edited the question trying to precise why ships handling faster acceleration changes (breaking and picking up speed). I kinda assume that passengers want to arrive at the destination quicker rather than enjoying the trip through space
Also yeah I realize that the distances are short.

If your main concern is just the ships withstanding 1-g acceleration, keep in mind that the force that accelerates them that fast is the same force they experience sitting on their engines on the surface of the Earth. If they don't fall apart on the ground, they'll withstand 1-g in space.

A spaceship that travels with a constant acceleration / deceleration of 1 G is optimal. In this case, artificial gravity from rotation is unnecessary, and the crew can operate in a 1 G environment by constructing the floor on the side with the rocket nozzle. However, in situations where full acceleration is not possible (such as being near a station or experiencing accident), they will likely float.
If your focus is on maintaining a constant 1 G at all times, you need to rotate the ship like a torus or cylinder. By increasing the rotation to compensate for the engine's output, it is theoretically possible to maintain a constant 1 G. The problem arises because the directions of centrifugal force from rotation and inertial force from the rocket differ. As the ratio of these vectors changes, the surface that should serve as the "floor" changes accordingly.
One idea to reconcile this is a ship like a mobile hanging above a crib. The living quarters are connected to the core by ropes or tubes. The appropriate angular velocity ω is determined from the desired acceleration g for the crew and the rocket’s acceleration a (0<=a<=g).


Haha, neat idea. I imagine the captain announcing: "We are about to engage the stardrive. Please fasten your seatbelt and secure the supplied sick-bag over your mouth ...".

Data is always faster then physical travel. You send a stack of matter there and build whatever you want to build in place.
You want to go there in person? You rent a pre-existing dolly, that looks and feels like a human and control it in your sleep. Goto sleep on the other side of the system and you wake up at home.
Its cheap, its data-based and fast. Your Sci-Fi instincts want to fight it, you want spaceships, megastructures, you want to travel over- but thats a buisness trip for what could be a teams meeting.

Interesting. I think that's neat for business trips and diplomatic visits. However, it could be prone to hacking/fake data. When do you think we could achieve this in the real world?

Impossible. At 20'000'000 km time delay would be at least 66 seconds one -way. No interactive control is possible. If between you pressing a button and seeing the effect 2 minutes passes the whole thing is pointless.

Light delay is fun. You could do an behaviour image and prediction, but yes, thats a killer argument right there. Then again its negotiation.  Chat GPT do a filler loop, until my reaction arrives.
